# Existence and Construction of Holomorphic Self-map of the Open Unit Disk with Finite Constrains

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to figure out the following question: Let $f: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ to be a holomorphic mapping, where $\mathbb{D}= \{z\in \mathbb{C}| |z|<1\}$ is the open unit disk of a complex plane. We further assume that there are $n = 4$ points $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4 \in \mathbb{D}$ and another $n = 4$ points $z^*_1, z^*_2, z^*_3, z_4^*\in \mathbb{D}$ such that $f(z_i) = z_i^*, i = 1,2,3,4$. Then the questions are:

(1) Does $f$ exist?

(2) Any chance to construct such $f$?

(3) Can these results be generalized towards any finite $n$?

I tried to come up with some polynomials, but haven't got any luck yet...

Comment: Try linear fractional / Moebius transformations ... The constraint of mapping the disk to itself makes it harder to map some number of arbitrary points to specified points... Even with just two, it is not always possible... (Schwarz' lemma helps classify the self-maps of the open disk.)

Comment: See [Nevanlinna-Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nevanlinna%E2%80%93Pick_interpolation)

Comment: Thanks @nicomezi, I read your link and understood that it relates to a condition of whether certain matrix is p.s.d.. But still I didn't get the intuition on that condition... Any possible explanation?

Comment: It is hard to have an intuition on this unfortunately. It is connected to the pseudo-hyperbolic distance between the points. This distance between two points is tied to some Moebius transformation, which are also the biholormorphic functions of the unit disc. In fact the demonstration of this theorem gives an algorithm to construct such function. I think you can find it in "Bounded analytic functions" of John B. Garnett.

Comment: Thanks @nicomezi! Actually I am indeed considering a problem involving hyperbolic embedding with discrete points. Here's another [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4063647). It would be a huge help if you could also take a look at that one:)